# Wildfly swarm - Page not found error

Tags: maven, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

This is the pom.xml file that I have

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hu.javacity.app.buildingsofcities</groupId>
    <artifactId>city</artifactId>
    <name>WildFly Swarm Example</name>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <version.wildfly.swarm>2018.4.1</version.wildfly.swarm>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
        <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <finalName>demo</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>package</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Java EE 7 dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- WildFly Swarm Fractions -->

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And this would be HelloWorldEndpoint.java

```
package hu.javacity.app.buildingsofcities.city.rest;


import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;


@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldEndpoint {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public Response doGet() {
        return Response.ok("Hello from WildFly Swarm!").build();
    }
}
```

After running Maven, It says: "WildFly Swarm is ready" and I get no errors So im trying to write the following URL in: localhost:8080/hello The result is the following message: "not found" I tried using Edge, Firefox or Chrome, but to no success.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few problems here.  First, you are missing the `JAX-RS` Swarm Fraction.  This means that the dependencies in your `pom.xml` need to look like:

```
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Java EE 7 dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- WildFly Swarm Fractions -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Now the second problem.  In the `2018.4.1` version of Wildfly Swarm the swarm team removed the automatic generation of the `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` that is required for standard JAX-RS applications (see [this blog](http://wildfly-swarm.io/posts/announcing-wildfly-swarm-2018-4-1/) for more information).  If you try to start your code in `2018.4.1` you'll get a warning:

> WFLYRS0015: No Servlet declaration found for JAX-RS application.  In
>   demo.war either provide a class that extends
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Application or declare a servlet class in web.xml.

And your application doesn't work.  So you have two choices to fix *that* issue.  The first is to just use `2018.3.1` as it does do the auto generation.  However, that's a poor fix as, going forward, Swarm will likely continue the behavior of the `2018.4.1` release.  So to fix it you need to add your own `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` that could look something like:

```
package hu.javacity.app.buildingsofcities.city.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    // intentionally empty
}
```

This sets up your `JAX-RS` path to be `/`. A common pattern is to use something like `/rest` or `/svc` but for now this will work fine for you.

Comment: Specifying Jax-RS dependency isn't really recommended in this case. Swarm has gotten pretty great at auto-detection.